# Uniform convergence of a series of functions with arctan

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, trigonometry, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to solve the following problem about the uniform convergence of a series of functions involving the function arctan(x).

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[1-\frac{n}{x^{2n}}\arctan\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\right)\right]  $$

I have to study the pointwise and uniform convergence of the series for $$x\neq0$$
I started to check where it is possible to have pointwise convergence by claculating this limit
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[1-\frac{n}{x^{2n}}\arctan\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\right)\right]  $$
It turns out that for $ -1\le x \le 1 , x\neq 0  $ the limit is $ 0$ so it is possible to have pointwise convergence in $ [-1,1], x\neq 0$. For $ \vert x\vert \gt 1$ the limit is 1, so there's no way the series can have pointwise convergence in $ (-\infty , -1) \cup (1 , +\infty)$. I decided to check all of this stuff so I know where to look for uniform convergence better, and once I find it I will also know where the pointwise convergence is , correct?

I started by observing that $\left[1-\dfrac{n}{x^{2n}}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n}\right) \right]\ge 0 $  for  $-1 \le x \le 1$ . The problem is that I can't find a way to bound this function with a sequence $Mn$ such that $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty Mi $ converges. Any tips??

Comment: The inequality $x-\frac{x^3}3\le\arctan x\le x$ could help.

Comment: Intresting, where does it come from?

Comment: For instance by studying functions or integrating the easier inequality $1-x^2\le\frac1{1+x^2}\le 1$. You could also use Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Does the inequality work for all real x?

Comment: for $x\ge0$; one can use a similar one for $x\le0$.

Comment: I think I solved it using taylor

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor's theorem, $$ \frac{x^{2n}}{n}-\frac{x^{6n}}{3n^3} \le \arctan\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\right)\le\frac{x^{2n}}n $$ so $$0\le\left[1-\frac{n}{x^{2n}}\arctan\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\right)\right] \le1-\frac{n}{x^{2n}}\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n}-\frac{x^{6n}}{3n^3}\right)= \frac{x^{4n}}{3n^2} \le \frac{1}{3n^2}.$$ If $ M_n=\frac{1}{3n^2} $ then $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges thus the series converges uniformly.

Comment: I think it is rather $\frac{x^{2n}}n\color{red}{-}\frac{x^{6n}}{3n}\le\arctan\frac{x^{2n}}n$. There are other typos, but you got the idea. This is for $x\ge0$. You should also deal with the case $x\le0$.

Comment: Why do you think that there's a difference betwenn the case $ x \geq 0 $ an $ x \leq 0 $ ? The even powers should do the trick for this

Comment: You are right! I hadn't paid attention to that. Note also that you need $|f_n(x)|\le M_n$, not just $f_n(x)\le M_n$. (Here you indeed have $|f_n(x)|\le M_n$ because you have showed $f_n(x)\ge0$.)

Comment: Yes so it is correct !!! I'm so happy, thank you for mentioning Taylor theorem

Comment: I took the liberty to correct remaining typos in your answer. Feel free to check again.

Comment: thank you very much